# Python - Verificação de itens em uma lista

Tags: python, lista, for

Estou com um cenário, um pouco confuso de explicar... mas vou tentar...

Preciso comparar `listA` com `listaB`, onde caso 1 ou mais itens da `listaA` estejam dentro da `listaB`, eu printo isso na tela, mas caso na `listaB` tenha algum item que não esteja na `listaA`, nada aconteça.

As listas são parecidas com as abaixo:

```
dns_svc = ['DNS', 's-udp-53', 's-tcp-53', 'junos-dns-udp', 'junos-dns-tcp']

app1 = ['s-tcp-443', 'Domain-logon']
app2 = ['s-tcp-443', 'DNS']
app3 = ['s-udp-53', 's-tcp-80']
app4 = ['DNS']
app5 = ['s-tdp-53', 's-udp-53']
app6 = ['junos-dns-udp', 'junos-dns-tcp']
```

`dns_svc` seria a `listaA`, enquanto que as listas `appx` são a `listaB`.

Se alguém poder dar uma sugestão.

Fiz o script abaixo, mas ele está me trazendo mais linhas do que deveria. Ele deveria me trazer 3 linhas:

```
app1 = ['tcp-443', 'Domain-logon']
app2 = ['tcp-443', 'DNS']
app3 = ['udp-53', 'tcp-80']
app4 = ['DNS']
app5 = ['tcp-53', 's-udp-53']
app6 = ['junos-dns-udp', 'junos-dns-tcp']
applist = [app1, app2, app3, app4, app5, app6]

dns_svc = ['DNS', 's-udp-53', 's-tcp-53', 'junos-dns-udp', 'junos-dns-tcp']

for i in dns_svc:
    for a in applist:
        if i in a:
            print(i)
```

Comment: Esses itens nas listas, eles podem se repetir dentro de cada lista ou são itens únicos dentro de cada lista?

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução para imprimir os dados únicos que estão tanto na listaA e na listaB eu utilizei o set que é uma coleção de items onde não pode ter valores duplicados

Segue o código:

```
dns_svc = ['DNS', 's-udp-53', 's-tcp-53', 'junos-dns-udp', 'junos-dns-tcp']

app1 = ['tcp-443', 'Domain-logon']
app2 = ['tcp-443', 'DNS']
app3 = ['udp-53', 'tcp-80']
app4 = ['DNS']
app5 = ['tcp-53', 's-udp-53']
app6 = ['junos-dns-udp', 'junos-dns-tcp']
applist = [app1, app2, app3, app4, app5, app6]

items = set()

for i in dns_svc:
    for a in applist:
        if i in a:
            items.add(i)

for item in items:
    print(item)
```

o resultado após rodar o código:

```
junos-dns-udp
DNS
junos-dns-tcp
s-udp-53
```

Answer (score -1):

Kaique, muito obrigado! Eu estava tentando aqui e acho que consegui tbm... Mas a sua sugestão parece ser muito mais eficiente (to começando ainda...), mais simples e mais claro :). De qualquer forma segue como eu fiz:

```
app1 = ['s-tcp-443', 'Domain-logon']
app2 = ['s-tcp-443', 'DNS']
app3 = ['s-udp-53', 's-tcp-80']
app4 = ['DNS']
app5 = ['s-tcp-53', 's-udp-53']
app6 = ['junos-dns-udp', 'junos-dns-tcp']
app7 = ['junos-dns-udp']
app8 = ['s-tcp-53', 'DNS']

def comparing(lst):
    dns_svc = ['DNS', 's-udp-53', 's-tcp-53', 'junos-dns-udp', 'junos-dns-tcp']
    flag = True
    for ap in lst:
        if ap not in dns_svc:
            flag = False
            continue
        else:
            if flag:
                flag = True

    return flag

applist = [app1, app2, app3, app4, app5, app6, app7, app8]

for app in applist:
    a = comparing(app)
    if a:
        print(app)
```